# Should questions about working with contractors/subcontractors be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

The name of the site implies questions geared towards DIYers and contractors, but I think there is a lot of potential for good questions related to hiring and working with contractors?

Examples:

- What is a good source to find reliable contractors?
- If I am a novice for a given trade (electrician, plumber, concrete) how do I vet contractors when hiring them?

What do you think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I say on-topic.  Working with contractors is a big part of home improvement for all but the most die-hard DIY-ers.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's OK as long as they are general and aren't too localized (e.g. "Anybody know of any good electricians in Mytown, Ohio?")

Answer (score 3):

Gets my vote. Working with others (and knowing where others can help, when you might least expect it!) is as important a skill as doing stuff yourself.